# SQL Query is not working as it should

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So basically I have a table -

```
ID | from | To

-----------------
1  | 25.05.2012|30.05.2012
-----------------
2  | 15.05.2012|20.05.2012
-----------------
3  | 25.06.2012|30.06.2012
```

and I have a query

```
SELECT date.*
FROM table AS date
WHERE (date.from >= '25.05.2012' OR date.to >= '25.06.2012' )  AND (date.to <= '30.05.2012' OR date.from <= '25.05.2012' )
GROUP by date.id
```

but it's not working, what could be the problem?

Comment: A table is more than just the data in it. What is the schema?

Comment: Whats the problem/error you are facing?

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if you have any concerns..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, try calling the table something else!

Comment: Changed, but didn't fix, it doesn't connect two selects together. Oh no, I was wrong, it fixed, lol thankS!

Answer (score 1):

You are performing string comparisons, not date comparisons, eg: `26.05` is greater than `25.06` since the comparison only reaches as far as the second character of the string and determines that `6` is greater than `5`.

In order to perform date comparisons you either need to store the value as a date (preferable) or in an appropriate string form eg `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: Hello, okay, It was just a example, by default there is date, but I was too lazy to write it currently, edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (from >= '25.05.2012' AND to <= '25.05.2012') GROUP by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

"date" is a reserved string in MySQL. I'd recommend renaming all tables and columns with that name to a custom one. This might already solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1 :** table, date, from are reserved keywords. Those should not be used for naming tables. If your table name is table, use backticks

**Point 2 :** When you have one table why you are creating alias for that?

**Point 3 :** While comparing date should be in format of `yyyy-mm-dd`. I believe `from` and `to` columns are timestamp.

**Point 4 :** No need of GROUP BY statement at the moment as you are not using any aggregate function such as `SUM, COUNT, etc`

Your query should be

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE 
    (`from`>= '2012-05-25' OR `to`>= '2012-06-25' ) 
    AND
    (`to` <= '2012-05-30' OR `from` <= '2012-05-25');
```

If you want to pass date as `25.05.2012` , use **[STR_TO_DATE](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/SELECTSTRTODATE04312004mdY.htm)** function to convert string to date.